# If a check is written out to me, can I come with my boyfriend to have it deposited into his bank account?

Tags: check, deposits

We got a refund check and the dealership had put my name on the check. However, we need the money to go to my boyfriend's account. If I go up to the bank with him and explain that I want this check deposited in his account will they let us do that? To be clear, we do not have the same banking company.

Answer (score 5):

The right way to do this is to endorse the check by signing the back, then write "Pay to the order of " followed by that person's name.

However, since this process is highly susceptible to fraud (someone could just take a check that you endorsed, or forge an endorsement, and sign it over), not all banks allow this. If you are there to prove that you endorsed the check in the first place, it might reassure the bank.

Bottom line: go to your boyfriend's bank before endorsing the check, explaining what you want to do, and they'll tell you how to do it. It will be very helpful if you're there with identification to verify that you endorsed the check in the first place.

Comment: Or.... cash check at bank one. Give cash to boyfriend. Boyfriend deposits cash in bank two. Sure, may take an extra 20 mins, but it's like 0 risk of anyone thinking something sketchy or untoward is happening.

Comment: Sure - or deposit and paypal/venmo/etc. I was just answering the specific question of depositing a check in an account other than the payee's.

Comment: I am not disagreeing, Mr Stanley. Just saying that cashing at one bank, handing cash over, then depositing cash into boyfriend's bank ends up with the exact same desired result ($ in boyfriend's account) without the risk of the bank(s) in question interrogating.

Comment: @R.Hamilton Your suggestion would probably be the default option. I suspect OP has a reason they don't want to do that. I would be interested to hear what it is though...

Comment: Or take the check to his bank, tell them you want to deposit it in his account, and convince them that you are the person it is addressed to.

Comment: @WGroleau That doesn't work. A check has to be signed by the account holder (i.e. boyfriend) for the bank to accept it as a deposit to his account, at which point you're doing exactly what this answer tells you to. ([UCC 3-201](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/3/3-201))

Comment: @user71659: Not so.  I have often deposited checks written to my wife OR to me into an account that has only her name on it.  There were two occasions when they wouldn't accept one made to her because she hadn't endorsed it.  I just walked a few steps to the ATM and deposited it anyway.  We have also had other people go to two different credit unions and put cash into our accounts.  (All USA, but I have used ATMs in Spain to make deposits into other people's accounts.)

Comment: @WGroleau The issue isn't with the deposit, the issue is with checks and the law, which I linked to. Cash deposits are different. A check endorsement is required or else the bank takes on certain legal risks (a complex issue in itself). Practically, banks certainly don't validate every signature and often don't even check presence, but as you experienced, they have the right to reject unendorsed or improperly endorsed checks. Intentional abuse, like you're doing by putting it in the ATM might get your account closed, if they so desired.

Comment: @WGroleau For example, the check is deposited without a proper endorsement like this answer says. There's a dispute and the girlfriends in this case says I never gave the check to the boyfriend, he stole it. Without the endorsement, the boyfriend never made a warranty of good title on the instrument to the bank... he never indicated that he was entitled to the money. The girlfriend can sue the bank and recover the amount from the bank because the bank accepted an essentially stolen check.

Comment: "If an instrument is payable to bearer, it may be negotiated by transfer of possession alone."  When a check is payable to the owner of the card used to deposit it, they have no motivation to study the video to find out if someone else did it.  But the main point is that both of our credit unions are quite happy to let anyone at all deposit things into our accounts.  As is Schwab Bank, where my sister deposited money into my account frequently.  Endorsed by the person it is payable to, not by the account owner.

Comment: @WGroleau Payable to bearer means the check is made out to "bearer" or "cash". It's not relevant here. The "video" or card has nothing to do with it. It all has to do with contract law and the UCC. Again, cash or electronic transactions is not relevant to this discussion. Checks are actually contracts, that's why there's signature rules. They may be happy, but wait until there's a legal dispute like I described and lawyers get involved.

Comment: I repeat: two institutions in USA and more than one in Spain accept deposits without question from people not the owner of the account. (and without that person present)